# What is the easiest way to print a DateTime using an hour adjustment instead of a locale?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am working on a system where each user can specify a setting of their adjustment from UTC in hours.

So when a date/time is input from this user, the value is adjusted by their setting and saved as UTC. Similarly, on the way out, the date/time is retrieved from the database, adjusted per their setting and displayed.

I might be thinking about this too much, but does this mean to show the correct date/time for each person, I have to effectively adjust the hours and tell the instance of my SimpleDateFormat that this is "UTC"? Right now I am in the UK where the current time zone is UTC+1 and if I don't specify to print in UTC then the time is off by one hour!

```
DateTime dateWithOffset = statusDate.plusMinutes(currentTimezoneOffsetInMinutes);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
return sdf.format(dateTime.toDate());
```

Am I thinking about this correctly? Or is there an easier way to print a date in a format given that I just want an hours adjustment from UTC?

Comment: Would the `setRawOffset` method of the `TimeZone` class  work for you?

Comment: Minor inconsistency; Your first sentence says hours but your code says minutes.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks! I tried to simplify the question as much as possible! We save the offset in minutes so it would be 60, 120, etc. Thank you for your detailed answer, I will read and understand it properly on Monday, right now it's the weekend!

Comment: @DavidSpence What did you mean by `locale` in the title? No mention in the rest of the Question.

Comment: Probably not the correct term. I meant that the user does not choose their country etc. I'm not sure how common the approach is, choosing the number of hours offset from UTC as a user setting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working too hard. Never do manual adjustments for offsets and time zones, never be adding or subtracting minutes to a date-time value for that purpose. Let a decent date-time library do that work.

## java.time

The Joda-Time team advises us to migrate to the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class represents an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Keep in mind that in some areas an offset may involve not only a number of hours but also minutes and even seconds.

The [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class represents a a moment in the timeline with an assigned offset.

```
int hours = 3;  // input by user

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( hours );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset );
```

The standard ISO 8601 formats are used by the toString methods in java.time.

```
String output = odt.toString();
```

Generally the best practice is to do your business logic and data storage in UTC. Convert to/from an offset or zoned value only for interaction with user.

In java.time a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is represented by the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. You can extract an `Instant` object from the `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toString();
```

Both this `Instant` and this `OffsetDateTime` represent the **same simultaneous moment** on the timeline. They present different [wall-clock times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time).

It may be more clear to skip the use of the [`OffsetDateTime.now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) convenience method and start with `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Always in UTC, by definition.
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( hours );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , offset );  // Same moment but presenting alternate wall-clock time.
```

### Handling input

If the user is inputting date-time values as strings, we need to parse. In java.time that means the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. The formatting codes are similar to the outmoded `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly identical, so be sure to study the doc.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu HH:mm";
```

Since the offset-from-UTC is given separately, we parse this input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) devoid of time zone information.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( inputString , formatter );
```

To view, create a String object formatted in ISO 8601 format by calling `ldt.toString()`.

> 2016-01-02T12:34:45

Apply the pre-determined `ZoneOffset` object to yield a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset );
```

> 2016-01-12T12:34:45+03:00

### Think in UTC

Handling date-time values is a headache. [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is your aspirin.

When a programmer arrives at the office, she should take off her “UK citizen / London resident” hat, and put on her “UTC” hat. Forget all about your own local time zone. Learn to think in UTC (and 24-hour clock). Add another clock to your desk or computer, set to UTC (or [Reykjavík](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reykjav%C3%ADk) Iceland), or at least bookmark a page like [time.is/UTC](http://time.is/UTC). Do all your logging, business logic, data serialization, data-exchange, and debugging in UTC.

Make `Instant` your first-thought, your go-to class. It's value is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Look at the `Instant` extracted from the `OffsetDateTime` value we saw above whose String representation was `2016-01-12T12:34:45+03:00`. Being in UTC means 9 AM rather than noon, same moment but three hours difference in wall-clock time. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

```
String output = odt.toInstant().toString();
```

> 2016-01-12T09:34:45Z

Adjust into an offset or time zone only as needed, when expected by a user or data sink. FYI, a time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). **Use a time zone in preference to a mere offset** wherever possible.

The `Europe/London` time zone is the same as UTC in the summer, but in winter uses Daylight Saving Time nonsense, and is one hour ahead of UTC. So using the same `Instant` seen just above, the London wall-clock time is 10 AM rather than 9 AM in UTC, and different from the noon we saw with an offset of `+03:00`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

> 2016-01-12T10:34:45+01:00[Europe/London]

Always specify the desired/required offset or time zone; never rely on the implicit current default by omitting this optional argument. (Ditto for [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) by the way.) Note how in all the code of this answer the fact that your [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) has a current default time zone ([`ZoneId.systemDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--)) of [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London) and the fact that my JVM has a current default time zone of [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles) is *completely irrelevant*. The code runs the same, gets the same results, regardless of whatever machine you use to develop, test, and deploy.

## Locale

Specify a `Locale` object when generating a textual representation of a date-time value that involves a name of month or day, commas or periods and so on. The `Locale` determines (a) the human language to use when translating such names, and (b) the cultural norms to follow in deciding issues such as punctuation marks.

The `Locale` has nothing to do with time zones and offset-from-UTC. For example, you could use [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH) with a date-time zoned for [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) if you had a [Québécois](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_(word)) user in India.

Comment: Thank you for putting the time into writing such a detailed answer.